# Outlook Web App doesn't show contact name

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

I'm working on a CRM application to sync CRM data to Exchange using a service I'm writing in C#.  After instiating the EWS connection:

```
ExchangeService es = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
es.AutodiscoverUrl("SamGam@TheShire.com");
```

I can create a contact and edit the details:

```
...
Contact contact = new Contact(es);
contact.GivenName = "Samwise";
contact.Surname = "Gamgee";
contact.DisplayName = "Samwise Gamgee";
...
```

Then save it

```
...
contact.Save();
```

And now it will appear in the user's exchange contact mailbox.  In the desktop version of Outlook it looks ok:

[image: Desktop Outlook]

But in the Outlook web app I see this:

[image: Web App Outlook]

Not showing the name and having Untitled Contact eliminates any usability for a real user.  If I double click on the contact in the list to edit the details I get this showing the First name and Last name.

[image]

And then if I save it the name will appear in the contact list and view details.

Is there anything I can do to have it appear in the list automatically for users who use the outlook web app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the FileAs mapping and I would also always set the Subject field to the displayname as this can also cause problems eg

```
contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameCommaGivenName;
contact.Subject = "Samwise Gamgee";
```

On 2013 and Office365 there is also a few other properties you should set see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90d7e749-977e-4191-87cf-725007a326b4/contacts-created-by-ews-v20-are-visible-in-outlook-but-not-in-owa-in-office-365?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment